# How to make my one starting and ending date-time format in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to get Business start Date&Time and Business End Date&Time, which starts from 7:00 am to 7:00 am.
what I want to do is to make a query for `mysql` to select data between Start and End date.
For example:

```
$start_date = 2015-27-11 7:00:am; 
$end_date = 2015-28-11 7:00:am;
```

between these time should be count **one business day**.

```
Select * from orders where time > $start_date AND time < $end_date;
```

How to make time and Date for it? please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why all the tags that have nothing to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `DATE()` :

`SELECT * WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN ':start' AND ':end';`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question (Which you have to reformulate), Why don't you save the time and date in one field of type: Datetime?! This way, you will be able to make your comparison query easily.

```
Select * from orders where time>$start_date_and_time AND time < $end_date_and_time
```

Comment: In this way I can get. but I want to make the Business Start time 7:00am and ending at the same by default. Start day and time should be current day + 7:00. the above query is fine till 11:59:00 pm, after that the day changes and this query remains of no use. what a query which change current date + 7:00 am starting and current date + 6:59 am as ending.
In this way two dates involves in this query. one from 7:00 am to 11:59 pm and the other is 12:00 pm to 6:59 am.